# How can I create new spreadsheet worksheets in Ruby using the Spreadsheet gem?

Tags: ruby, excel, spreadsheet, worksheet

Specifically what I am trying to do is add new worksheets alongside ones already there. I've tried to use `book.create_worksheet :name => 'new_sheet'` but it overwrites the previous worksheet.

I searched the site here and saw some people using a different gem that allowed "book.add_worksheet" (the Spreadsheet gem is supposed to have support for other gems, like it's supposed to be like 3 gems in 1 or something...) and that almost worked as well but I get the error `undefined method 'workbook=' for "new_sheet":String (NoMethodError)` when doing the line `sheet = book.add_worksheet("new_sheet")`.

Another thing I tried was `sheet = Spreadsheet::Worksheet.new` and I see on [the Spreadsheet rubyforge page](http://spreadsheet.rubyforge.org/Spreadsheet/Worksheet.html) that there is the public class method `new(opts={})` which, if you click to see the code, includes the line `@name = opts[:name] || Worksheet` which leads me to believe I should be able to use this to create and name a new worksheet, but I can't figure out the correct syntax.

Is what I am attempting possible? It seems like I'm getting close but I'm not quite hitting it.

Answer (score 1):

`book.create_worksheet(:name => 'unique_name')` works for me!

```
book = Spreadsheet::Workbook.new
sheet1 = book.create_worksheet(:name => 'AAA')
sheet2 = book.create_worksheet(:name => 'BBB')


sheet1.row(0).concat %w{Name Country Acknowlegement}
sheet1[1,0] = 'Japan'
row = sheet1.row(1)
row.push 'Creator of Ruby'
row.unshift 'Yukihiro Matsumoto'
sheet1.row(2).replace [ 'Daniel J. Berger', 'U.S.A.',
                  'Author of original code for Spreadsheet::Excel' ]
sheet1.row(3).push 'Charles Lowe', 'Author of the ruby-ole Library'
sheet1.row(3).insert 1, 'Unknown'
sheet1.update_row 4, 'Hannes Wyss', 'Switzerland', 'Author'

sheet2.row(0).concat %w{NAME COUNYRY ACK}
sheet2[1,0] = 'JAPAN'
row = sheet2.row(1)
row.push 'CREATOR OF RUBY'
row.unshift 'YUKIHIRO MATSUMOTO'
sheet2.row(2).replace [ 'DANIEL J. BERGER', 'U.S.A.',
                  'AUTHOR OF ORIGINAL CODE FOR  Spreadsheet::Excel' ]
sheet2.row(3).push 'CHARLES LOWE', 'AUTHOR OF THE RUBY-OLE LIBRARY'
sheet2.row(3).insert 1, 'UNKNOWN'
sheet2.update_row 4, 'HANNES WYSS', 'SWITZERLAND', 'AUTHOR'

book.write '/Users/stephen/tmp/test2.xls'
```

The above, lifted pretty much verbatim from the documentation works a treat.

Comment: Indeed that would work for hard-coded sheets. I guess I should have mentioned I was creating them on-the-fly with a tool I am writing. The tool asks for a name for the sheet and creates it. I figured out my earlier error (I was accidentally re-writing the entire workbook) and now I run into a couple of different results: If I write to the same filename it becomes corrupt, and if I write to a different file name and try to re-name it, I encounter an access error. I can't seem to find a "close" method to match the "Spreadsheet.open" which I was hoping would get rid of the access error. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that you can create many sheets with the same variable, you just have to change the name you put on it. For example:

articles.each do |art|
  sheet1 = book.create_worksheet :name => art.code
end